# Finding a solution to a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

What is the solution to this equation:

$\qquad r^{\prime\prime}(t)=c\,r(t)^{-2}$,

That is, the 2nd derivative of $r$ is $c\,/r(t)^{2}$, and $r$ is a function  of $t$ and $c$ is a constant. Also, the derivative is with respect to $t$.

Comment: If you want the Mathematica command, it is `DSolve[r''[t]==c/r[t]^2,r[t],t]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so much of an answer, rather an extended comment with some observations.

@Nasser gave the solution to the question. The `DSolve` is the command to use.

You should use

```
DSolve[r''[t] == c/r[t]^2, r[t], t ]
```

And if you run this, you will get an expression inside a solve. I am giving the result of DSolve below.

```
Solve[((c Log[-c + C[1] r[t] + 
       Sqrt[C[1]] Sqrt[C[1] - (2 c)/r[t]] r[t]])/C[1]^(3/2) + (
    Sqrt[C[1] - (2 c)/r[t]] r[t])/C[1])^2 == (t + C[2])^2, r[t]]
```

The above I think is a hint that *Mathematica* is trying to solve for the function $r(t)$, however, Solve doesn't know how to perform the calculation explicitly, if it is possible to do it analytically and not numerically.

For numerical solutions, you should use `NDSolve`. However *Mathematica* does not want to do that either.